# uitabbarcontroller + uitableviewcontroller + uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I'm using the code extracted from the URL http://www.iphonemusings.com/2009/01/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating.html to show initial screen with tab bar and having table view in both the tabs.
It is displaying the text in cells as well after taking necessary changes in table view delegate.
Now I want to show a view on click of table view. I'm using following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Latest* evnt = (Latest*)[latestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* url = [evnt URLLink];
    DetailedView* dv = [[DetailedView alloc] init];
        [dv.label setText=@"Testing label"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dv animated:YES];
    [dv release];
}
```

But it is not displaying any text. Can some one help me by pointing what mistake is in my code???

Answer (score 1):

Does this compile? `[dv.label setText=@"Testing label"];` is not Objective-C. It should read:

```
[dv.label setText:@"Testing label"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = contentView;

    ChatsViewController *chats=[[ChatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatsViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chats];  
    chats.title=@"Chats";

    ContactsViewController *contacts=[[ContactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *contacts1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contacts]; 

    contacts.title=@"Contacts";

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,contacts1,accounts1,settings1, nil]];

    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Try this code. The code will display `UITabBarController` with two tabs. You can create table in both tabs. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, write code for push a view using `navigationController`. When you select a row in the table it will display a new view.

```
SignInViewController *signIn=[[SignInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignInViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:signIn animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

copy all this code and paste it at existing  it will work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Latest* evnt = (Latest*)[latestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* url = [evnt URLLink];
    DetailedView* dv = [[DetailedView alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dv animated:YES];
 [dv.label setText=@"Testing label"];
    [dv release];
}
```